# unable to find valid certification path to requested target(sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: )

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

I have a worklight application which is deployed on worklight V6.0, trying to hit LDAP server for authentication...and trying for https enablement for the application.

**I am getting below exceptions.**

> javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target]; remaining name
>   'ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com'
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the LDAP server secured by self signed key and the worklight keystore hasn't its public certificate.
Check the keystore defined by "*ssl.keystore.**" in *worklight.properties* file and import LDAP certificate into the keystore if it needed.

Comment: Sorry, not this keystore, it is for adapter-backend connection. You nedd to check default java keystore or OS kestore on the machine where worklight run.

Comment: Thanks for the response and updates. issue got resolved by importing certificates to the keystore by the admin.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me:

Install the certificate using `keytool` command in the correct `jre` folder. My eclipse was using the jre for execution and earlier I installed the certificates in `jdk` folder.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -alias LDAPRoot -import -file "xxxxxxxx.cer
```